# Working WebPack setup with react, typescript and HMR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-hmr

I'm trying to get WebPack to work with ReactJs components written in Typescript (.tsx) and take advantage of WebPack's hot module replacement. I've found several recipes that describe how to do this, but they all seem to have the same problem - if you have a field on your component class that you use in the render method, then changing it in code does not trigger HMR properly, e.g.

```
export default class Counter extends React.Component<ICounterProps, ICounterState> {
        ...
    label: string = 'Counter';
    render() {
        return <h1>{this.label}: {this.state.counter}</h1>;
    }
}
```

If you modify the value of `label` in code, the page is not updated. I made an issue on GitHub in the [first](https://github.com/wmaurer/react-transform-boilerplate-ts/issues/5) starter project I found, then I tried a bunch more and they all have this issue. This is a big problem - if you can't be sure whether the page will update, it renders the whole HMR kinda pointless. 
Also, note that this works fine in vanilla .jsx components.

Does anyone have a way to make this work? Any direction would me much appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, there are numerous issues with HMR + React. It works really well for a certain class of changes (for instance, changing the "render" method) but many other changes don't really fit into react-proxy's view of the world (which basically just tries to proxy a React component). As a simple example, changes to an arrow function will not take effect (see https://github.com/gaearon/react-proxy/pull/8). Point just being, I would view HMR as more of a helper than a full-blown solution. Sometimes you just need to reload the page.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that, I was sort of hoping that it would recognize any change, much like the watch mode. If it is as you say, then it seems kind of useless to me, I mean what's the point if you constantly have to wonder whether you code is wrong or if HMR simply didn't pick up the changes...

Comment: I wound up finding confirmation that this is a known limitation. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the first "known limitation" from https://github.com/gaearon/react-proxy#known-limitations

> - Does not replace ES7 instance properties

Comment: Perfect, thanks for clearing up that mystery, at least that gives me some idea as to what I can and cannot expect to work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload your webpack's config?

And what package exatly are you using to power `Webpack's HMR` for `React's components`? 
`react-hot` or `babel-plugin-react-transform` ?

If you use `Babel 6` I would recommend to use `babel-preset-react-hmre`, which works well for me.

Comment: In general, I was focusing on `react-transform`, since that's the newer way of doing it. You can see the webpack.config in the repo I referenced (https://github.com/wmaurer/react-transform-boilerplate-ts). I also tried the one on https://github.com/keokilee/react-typescript-boilerplate. Both of them have the same issue. I also tried to add the react-hmre preset you mentioned, but still no luck :-(